# How to group a Flux into buckets and alert whenever a bucket does not reach some size after a period of time

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I was trying to find a reactive solution for the following problem: say I have a flux that contains elements looking like that:

```
class Node {
    boolean isParent;
    boolean isChild;
    int id;
    int parentId;
    // getters & setters
}
```

My `Flux<Node>` is "infinite" and contains both parent and children `Node`s. I want to alert whenever a parent is received and 3 children are not created within 5 seconds from parent creation. The original case included a Kafka subscription, but I want to know how could I do it in a more general case.

I tried using `windowWhen()` but it's not working correctly and I don't know how to specify the number of children wanted.

```
Flux<Node> myFlux = ... // defined somewhere earlier
myFlux
.windowWhen(
    myFlux.filter(node -> node.isParent()),
    parent -> myFlux
        .filter(node -> node.isChild && node.getParentId() == parent.getId())
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .doOnError(System.out::println))
            .subscribe();
```

This compiles alright and hits all the elements (at least so it seems from logs) but when I try to throttle `myFlux` with `delayElements()` I only get the following:

```
17:45:55.961 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.ConcatMapImmediate)
17:45:55.966 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - request(unbounded)
```

I am new to the subject of reactive programming so I am not even sure my initial idea of reusing the original stream to control the opening/closing of windows is correct...

Comment: Can you provide more details on the source `Flux<Node>`.  Is the stream ordered in that there is always a parent followed by all of its children, then another parent followed by all of its children, etc?  Or is it more intermixed in that there are multiple parents, and then children of those parents later in no particular order.  Does a parent always come before its children?  Are there multiple "levels" of parent/child relationships (e.g. can a parent also be a child of another parent, like a tree?)  Is it possible to determine when/if all children of a given parent have been emitted?

Comment: Let's assume the relationship is 'flat' i.e. children can't have more children. The ordering can be arbitrary: only constraint is that a parent must come before it's children e.g: p(arent)1, c(hild)1(of)p1, p2, c2p1, p3, c3p1, c1p2 etc. Ordering of children themselves  (or for the sake of simplicity even their uniqueness) is not relevant, I only care about a specific number of them arriving withing a specific amount of time. I don't quite understand the last question. Did you mean a separate channel, that informs that all children of a parent have been emitted?